# Does local Eclipse project affect statistics of central Sonar installation?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I'd like to see the violations shown by Sonar plugin in my local Eclipse environment. I tried to follow [this instruction](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse) and have a question on it. In Eclipse I have to set a Sonar server which runs the Sonar tests. If I set our central Sonar server, which is usually used for the whole project, as Eclipse Sonar runtime, do my local experiments affect the statistics our central Sonar server in any way or does the Eclipse plugin just need the server as some kind of "running instance" which just executes my project without affecting any statistics or something else on the server?

(I'm not very familiar with Sonar, that's why I'm not sure how the background processes really work there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your local analysis will not alter anything that is shown on your central server. The server is needed to fetch the quality profiles, the analysis will be done on your machine, and will not be stored in the sonar database. You can verify this easily by running a local analysis on your changed code, and then switching back to remote analysis, which will display the result of the last sonar analysis run for your central server. Any violations you fixed locally will be shown again.

Comment: Ok, I thought something like that, but wasn't 100% sure.